# How to compile typescript into raw ts files with type annotations and interface imports removed

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

We are currently running into an issue using Firebase Functions (with a typescript code base), where we have a separate library in our monorepo which is also in typescript, however this library imports types and interfaces via symlinks (yarn workspace) and annotates the files using them.

We are trying to use this library to have all our common utility functions etc and then copy a version of it into the 'functions' directory of cloud functions every time before we deploy, so that we don't have to manually copy the monorepo folder into it each time.

This is because the monorepo / symlinks don't work with cloud functions as it needs code to all be locally within your functions folder or on npm as a package and we cant publish part of our code base as a public package.

The thing we need to do is compile our utilities package, which has typescript annotations imported from another 'interfaces' library, into something which is raw typescript files but without these annotations or type / interface imports, as firebase functions can't then import them on its end if we don't do this.

In response to the question, what i mean is this:

function.ts

```
const { MyInterface } = require('interfaces');
const myFunction = (foo: MyInterface) => bar;
```

Then I want a stripped file with no annotations or type / interface imports like so:

function.ts (stripped)

```
const myFunction = (foo) => bar;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? I'm not understanding what you mean by "raw typescript files without annotations or imports".

Comment: Ok sorry please see updated question for example

Comment: and I should have said no type imports rather than no imports sorry

Answer (score 0):

Solved: (partially anyway)
What we ended up doing was using a shell script to first put the transpiled javascript folder into the functions directory, then run through and add

```
export {};
```

To the top of every file (to solve the 'cannot redeclare block scoped variable' issue), then it went through and just changed all those files to .ts extensions.

Admittedly not the world's most elegant solution but it works for now.